# Google Closure Compiler 100% typed

Tags: javascript, typing, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

How can I get my application to be 100% typed in regard to google closure compiler?

I already tagged everything with jsdoc comments. Is it even possible to get 100? I'm at 64,6%

Comment: Have you tried compiling the closure library itself? does it get 100%?

Comment: How are you determining "64,6%"?

Comment: It's what it writes in the command line ;) How the closure compiler determines that, I have no clue...perhaps typed variables per variables? Probably more complex though.

Comment: @huyz summary_detail_level 3, if you want to see it in the output

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It IS possible to achieve 100%. My own projects are 100% typed. The closure compiler can output warnings about expressions with unknown types. Unfortunately there is no command line option to enable this feature. You have to modify the source code to enable it:

1. Download the current sources:

   `git clone https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/`
2. Edit src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java and change the line `reportUnknownTypes = CheckLevel.OFF` to `reportUnknownTypes = CheckLevel.WARNING`
3. Compile the closure-compiler by simply calling `ant` in the root directory. The modified compiler.jar is now in the build directory.

When you use this modified compiler on your scripts then it spits out lots of warnings about all the expressions for which the compiler couldn't determine the type. When you fix all these warnings in your code then it is 100% typed.

Comment: Since Sven hasn't commented on the issue, I wanted to just say *thank you very much, it works!* Oh and +1 :)

Comment: Thanks! Just for those who are following the thread, the compiler moved to `git` now. Replace step 1 by `git clone https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/`

Comment: Today it is possible via command line by using `--jscomp_warning=reportUnknownTypes`.

Comment: Looks like step #2 has changed.  This worked for me: `options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroup.REPORT_UNKNOWN_TYPES, CheckLevel.WARNING)`

Answer (score 9):

The compiler has a flag you can set to make unknown types output a warning.

```
--jscomp_warning=reportUnknownTypes
```

You will also need to increase the warning level.

```
--warning_level=VERBOSE
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried compiling the goog.net.XhrIo as a test:

```
goog.require('goog.Uri.QueryData');
goog.require('goog.debug.ErrorHandler');
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');

goog.net.XhrIo;
```

when I compile this I have this result:

```
20-nov-2010 1:12:21 com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
WARNING: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s), 91,5% typed
JSC_USELESS_CODE. Suspicious code. This code lacks side-effects. Is there a bug? at test.js line 5 : 0
```

It seems as if the closure library itself is not 100% typed and I don't think the goal is to reach 100%. Javascript is not a statically typed language. Closure tries to bring some benefits of statically typed languages into javascript. Which is good. But that doesn't mean you have to bring in the burdens of this type of languages.

### EDIT:

I tried to compile an empty file and the result was 90.4%. I think this means that the base.js with all the primitive functions is not 100% typed. So I did some more experimenting and Found out that when I also put type information on all my local variables, the percentage goes up. I don't think it is necessary to put type information on all your local variables. I mean imagine this:

```
/** @type {number} */
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

This can't be the goal of compiling with the closure compiler. This is proven by the fact that compiling base.js doesn't result in 100%. I try to keep this number between 85% and 95% in my development. Depending on your time, programming style and the application you're working on this can vary off course. The best guideline is to try to keep the percentage constant throughout the development of your application, whether it's 60% or 90%. Just do as much typing as needed to keep you comfortable with your own code.

Comment: Your example is 100% typed even without the @type annotation. The compiler can determine the type from the usage of the variable. So the first assignment of a number to the variable declares the variable of type {number}. If your compiler has not given you a 100% then try a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

All the credits go to @kayahr but since time went by. I wanted to provide an update to his answer which is based on a old version of the compiler.

You need to recompile the source with type checking enforced. To do so:

1. download the source `git clone https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/` and go to `closure-compiler`
2. Edit `src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java` and set `checkTypes` to `true` in. You can also play around with all kinds of compilation and optimization variables.
3. Compile the code by running `ant`

Watch out though, `tightenTypes` is experimental and quite broken.