# Properly type instance variables with closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I cannot get to properly type the following piece of code:

```
/**                                                                                                                                                                                      
 * @constructor                                                                                                                                                                          
 */
function F() {
      this.a = 0;
};

/**                                                                                                                                                                                      
 * @type {function(number)}                                                                                                                                                              
 */
F.prototype.g = function(b) {
    this.a += b;
};
```

I get the following warning:

```
test.js:12: WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
    this.a += b;
    ^
```

How can I properly type `this` in this example?

-- EDIT --

If you want to see the warning, you need to set `reportUnknownTypes` to `true`as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230326/google-closure-compiler-100-typed). I am trying to get to 100% typed code and I figured I could not reach that for that simple a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/** @type {function(number)} */
```

doesn't specify the "this" type so it is unknown.  To specify it in that fashion you would want to use:

```
/** @type {function(this:F, number)}
```

Using "@param {number}" lets the compiler infer the "this" type from the fact it was declared on F's prototype.

Comment: Great! that makes a lot of sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need to use **@param {number} b** instead of **@type {function(number)}**. Typing with @param doesn't throw the warning. Doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but it works:

```
/**                                                                                                                                                                                      
 * @param {number} b                                                                                                                                                             
 */
F.prototype.g = function(b) {
    this.a += b;
};
```

--

Original answer:

I think it's because you didn't type a in your constructor. Try this:

```
/**                                                                                                                                                                                      
 * @constructor                                                                                                                                                                          
 */
function F() {

    /**
     * @type {number}
     * @private
     */
    this.a = 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work either. I read that you did not need to type native types in variable definitions (this is why I skipped the `@type {number}`, as for `@private` it is not necessary I think.

Comment: Thanks! Does not make a lot of sense I totally agree, I could never have found.