# Typing indexOf redefinition with Closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am trying to redefine `Array.prototype.indexOf` for old IE versions. I am having trouble typing it correctly according to Google Closure Compiler.

It says that the type of `@this` is wrong.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  /**                                                                                                                                                 
   * @this {Array}                                                                                                                                    
   * @param {*} item                                                                                                                                  
   * @param {number=} from: ignored 
   * @return {number}                                                                                                                                 
   */
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item, from) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I get the following output

```
test.js:12: WARNING - variable Array.prototype.indexOf redefined with type \
function (this:Array, *, number=): number, original definition at \
externs.zip//es3.js:633 with type function (this:Object, *, number=): number
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item, from) {
^
```

Surprisingly, changing `@this {Array}` by `@this {Object}` (though it does not make much sense) returns this even more obscure message:

```
test.js:12: WARNING - variable Array.prototype.indexOf redefined with type \
function (this:Object, *, number=): number, original definition at \
externs.zip//es3.js:633 with type function (this:Object, *, number=): number
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item, from) {
^
```

Any hint on how to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@suppress {duplicate}` to ignore this warning:

```
/**
 * @this {Array}
 * @param {*} item
 * @param {number=} from: ignored
 * @return {number}
 * @suppress {duplicate}
 */
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item, from) {
    // ...
}
```

I am not sure about the implications redefining the method has on optimizations from the Closure Compiler in ADVANCED mode, though.

Comment: Redefining should be fine as long as the signature exactly matches the original and the function doesn't cause side effects (since the original does not). That's what the other warning was about.

Answer (score 2):

Array methods are generic, they should in fact take an Array-like value.  The latest Closure Compiler defines it as:

```
/**
 * Available in ECMAScript 5, Mozilla 1.6+.
 * @param {T} obj
 * @param {number=} opt_fromIndex
 * @return {number}
 * @this {{length: number}|Array.<T>|string}
 * @nosideeffects
 * @template T
 * @see http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf
 */
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, opt_fromIndex) {};
```

Simply assigning the value works:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item, from) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Consider upgrading to a recent release of the Compiler.

Comment: Thanks but simply assigning the value returns the same warning `source.js:488: WARNING - variable Array.prototype.indexOf redefined with type function (this:Array, *, number=): number, original definition at externs.zip//es3.js:633 with type function (this:Object, *, number=): number`. I am using version 2508M which I downloaded a few weeks back. I believe it's the latest. The reason I am getting the warning is probably because I compiled with `"reportUnknownTypes = CheckLevel.WARNING"` to have strict typing.

Comment: Report unknown types would not affect this.  It is more likely that you compiler release is old.

Comment: That's weird, my build came from running `svn checkout http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ closure-compiler` a week ago. Version is 2508M.

Comment: Closure compiler moved to git a while ago:
https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/checkout

Comment: Thanks! I added a new answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230326/google-closure-compiler-100-typed so that other people don't stick to the older repo.